# Check/Uncheck checkboxes by clicking on their parent divs issue - jQuery

Tags: jquery

The following lines of code check/uncheck checkboxes by clicking on their parent div. The code works fine except one issue. The issue is when we click on the checkbox itself then it doesn't get checked. And if it is already checked by clicking on the checkbox text or its parent div then it doesn't get unchecked by clicking on the checkbox itself. How to resolve this issue? I want code working when I click on the checkbox and its label text and the whole parent div's width. Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/coder07/32owtyns/1/).

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Check/uncheck checkboxes clicking on its parent div
    $(".checkbox_option").click(function(){
        var chk = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
        if(chk.prop("checked") == false)
        {
            chk.prop("checked", true);
        }
        else
        {
            chk.prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#checkbox_options {
    border:2px solid #b8b8b8;
    height:200px;
    margin:100px auto;
    overflow:scroll;
    width:500px;
}

.checkbox_option {
    padding:2px 5px;
}

.checkbox_option input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-right:5px;
}

.checkbox_option:hover {
    background-color:#464646;
    color:#fff;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="checkbox_options">

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="1" id="cat_1" />
        <label for="cat_1">Category 1</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="2" id="cat_2" />
        <label for="cat_2">Category 2</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="3" id="cat_3" />
        <label for="cat_3">Category 3</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="4" id="cat_4" />
        <label for="cat_4">Category 4</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="5" id="cat_5" />
        <label for="cat_5">Category 5</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="6" id="cat_6" />
        <label for="cat_6">Category 6</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="7" id="cat_7" />
        <label for="cat_7">Category 7</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="8" id="cat_8" />
        <label for="cat_8">Category 8</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="9" id="cat_9" />
        <label for="cat_9">Category 9</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="10" id="cat_10" />
        <label for="cat_10">Category 10</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check updated code here [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/Luyj10vg/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/Luyj10vg/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".checkbox_option input[type='checkbox'],.checkbox_option label").on('click', 
    function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

    // Check/uncheck checkboxes clicking on its parent div
    $(".checkbox_option").click(function(){               
        var chk = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
        if(chk.is(":checked") == false)
        {
            chk.prop("checked", true);
        }
        else
        {
            chk.prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think it's because when you click on checkbox it triggers twice.
if you want to it work you need to stop propagation on checkbox click.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // Check/uncheck checkboxes clicking on its parent div
    $(".checkbox_option").click(function(event){
        var chk = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
        if(chk.prop("checked") == false)
        {
            chk.prop("checked", true);
        }
        else
        {
            chk.prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
$('.checkbox_option input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

[here is working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/32owtyns/3/)

but the better way to handle this example is by css. you can style your label tags to contain the whole row.

Comment: @user5307298 I posted css workaround as answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example with css:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32owtyns/4/)

```
    <div id="checkbox_options">

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="1" id="cat_1" />
        <label for="cat_1">Category 1</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="2" id="cat_2" />
        <label for="cat_2">Category 2</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="3" id="cat_3" />
        <label for="cat_3">Category 3</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="4" id="cat_4" />
        <label for="cat_4">Category 4</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="5" id="cat_5" />
        <label for="cat_5">Category 5</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="6" id="cat_6" />
        <label for="cat_6">Category 6</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="7" id="cat_7" />
        <label for="cat_7">Category 7</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="8" id="cat_8" />
        <label for="cat_8">Category 8</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="9" id="cat_9" />
        <label for="cat_9">Category 9</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox_option">
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="10" id="cat_10" />
        <label for="cat_10">Category 10</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
    #checkbox_options {
    border:2px solid #b8b8b8;
    height:200px;
    margin:100px auto;
    overflow:scroll;
    width:500px;
}

.checkbox_option {
    padding:2px 5px;
}

.checkbox_option input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-right:5px;
    width:13px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}

.checkbox_option:hover {
    background-color:#464646;
    color:#fff;
}
.checkbox_option label{
  width:calc(100% - 22px);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can just wrap the div inside a label tag

eg;

```
<label class="col-12" for="check_id"> your parent div here</label>
```

it works but not sure whether it is the right practice